# Load external java function through XQuery with Saxon

Tags: java, saxon

I can access Java class and methods when executing xquery with Saxon when they are declared correctly (through namespace pointing to package and class) but I wonder if there is a way to create a kind of "dynamic" class path at each run to load external jar file and search classes in it instead of in the current project/program classpath (as I cannot add all possible class in it).
So for instance I have something like :

```
declare namespace dpr="java:com.*****.atm.dpr.common.util.DPRConfigurationLoader";
declare variable $rules as node()* := doc(dpr:getApplicationProperty('Common','RulesFileLocation'))//category;
```

I can replace the path the real class with an emulated version but it means I must create each possible class on my side (not really a good way as it means a "patch" for each new java call...).

So if I provide a jar containing the classes I need is there a way to load it so that the namespace point to it ?
I know I can load .class file if they are on classpath, but 3 jar files entirely ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, Saxon doesn't require external classes to be on the classpath - it requires them to be accessible using the appropriate ClassLoader. If you understand ClassLoaders and are prepared to write your own or configure third-party offerings, then you can load classes from anywhere. All the hooks are there in Saxon if you want to do such things; but there's nothing packaged with the product.

Some of the thing you could try include:

- With `Configuration.setDynamicLoader()` you can change the way Saxon does dynamic loading of external classes, including the classes used for Java extension functions.
- With `Configuration.getDynamicLoader().setClassLoader()` you could provide a different ClassLoader for loading classes, for example a URLClassLoader.
- With `ProfessionalConfiguration.setExtensionBinder("java", XXX)` you could register a customized JavaExtensionLibrary, typically as a subclass of the standard one, allowing you to change the way URIs are mapped to Java classes and the way methods are selected (for example)

This is all very low-level system programming and is not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: "it requires them to be accessible using the appropriate ClassLoader"

Comment: So JavaExtensionFunctionFactory cannot be used for this purpose ?

"it requires them to be accessible using the appropriate ClassLoader"
What do you mean ?
I have example of URLClassLoader to load any jar dynamically but it is an "ugly" way to do the job.

Comment: I've added some more information. JavaExtensionFunctionFactory is supplied with a class and method that you want to call, so it's not so useful for what you want to achieve: it's more useful, for example, to control which classes and methods you're allowed to call, or to inject run-time tracing or diagnostics.

Comment: Working on a classloader but still having issues trying to load class from JAR file... (posted an other question to avoir mixing everything)